# Deleting from an ObservableCollection from a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm making a WPF application, and currently I'm having trouble deleting items from an ObservableCollection using the selected items in a DataGrid. The DataGrid uses the ObservableCollection as its ItemsSource. I made something that seemed to work until I started sorting the columns:

```
    Private Sub confirmDelete()
    Dim userAnswer As MessageBoxResult
    userAnswer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Selected Items?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
    If userAnswer = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        Dim index As Integer
        For i As Integer = grdReadings.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 'step backwards through list
            index = grdReadings.Items.IndexOf(grdReadings.SelectedItems(i))
            testDataList.RemoveAt(index)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

So this works fine if I never sort by any of the columns in the DataGrid, but as soon as I sort the DataGrid in a different order than the items were added, the index of selected items in the DataGrid doesn't match those item's indices in the ObservableCollection. Is there a better/easier way to delete items from an ObservableCollection using the items a user selects in the DataGrid?

Comment: Instead of using the index `Cast` the row object to it's underlying type and then delete that object from the collection.

Comment: I tried doing `For Each item In grdReadings.SelectedItems
                Dim removeRow As CCReading = CType(item, CCReading)
                testDataList.Remove(removeRow)
            Next` and this returned the same error as below: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Debug that, what does `item` show?

Comment: `item`'s value is `{Cap_Check.CCReading}`, and `removeRow`'s value is `{Cap_Check.CCReading}` as well.

Comment: Does the `collectionChanged` event fire with this?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: That collection object has a `CollectionChanged` event, make it just like any other object's events - either `WithEvents` modifier or `Addhandler` statement to point to a Sub that will handle it.

Comment: I used `WithEvents` and made a sub that handles `testDataList.CollectionChanged`. The `confirmDelete` function removes one entry from `testDataList`, the `collectionChanged` event fires, and then I get the "collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute" error.

Comment: That's what I was thinking - the error was been swallowed by the object.

Comment: I made an example with a collection of my class object - removed one and then set the `DataSource = Nothing` and then put the collection back to the Datasource and it worked fine. No enumeration took place - just casted the object and removed from the collection.

Comment: How are you sorting the columns?

Comment: I just click the `DataGrid` column headers and that sorts alphabetically or by value. I also need to allow for multiple lines to be selected and deleted at the same time. I posted my solution below and it works so far, if you have anything cleaner let me know but if not thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking up the index, you can directly delete the items

```
Private Sub confirmDelete()
    Dim userAnswer As MessageBoxResult
    userAnswer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete Selected Items?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
    If userAnswer = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        For each item in grdReadings.SelectedItems
            testDataList.Remove(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each` won't work on a collection if what's in the loop modifies the collection. This code gives the following error:                                         `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
        Dim itemsToRemove As New List(Of CCReading)
        For Each item In grdReadings.SelectedItems
            itemsToRemove.Add(item)
        Next
        For Each item In itemsToRemove
            testDataList.Remove(item)
        Next
        itemsToRemove.Clear()
```